# Python on Windows, connect to linux/unix server to process

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I work in an environment such that I have python installed on my laptop (windows 10). I also have access to a couple of Linux servers. I work with some very large datasets, some which would be too large for my machine's memory to handle.

My question, which I so far haven't found an answer to, is if it's possible to connect to the linux server and run the code from my windows PC. I want to take advantage of the processing and memory on the linux server, but don't want to log on to server and do all of my development there and execute the scripts on the linux environment.

As an aside, another person in my department has been asking if it's possible to do this from Jupyter Notebook or an IDE like Spyder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jupyter you could just run the Jupyter notebook on the server and connect to the server IP and edit the notebook locally.

Of course you'd have to save your local notebooks and import them on the server but that should be pretty straight forward.

You can see how to set up a public Jupyter instance on a server here:
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html

Comment: At present, the server isn't really used for anything Python related and only has version 2.6.6. The version on my windows machine is 3.6. Obviously if the server version isn't updated, then we'd have to develop code to Python 2.x in order to utilize the server.

Comment: Could you not just update python on the server or install python3.6 in parallel? 
How would you otherwise execute the python3.6-code on the server? I suppose you could statically compile it with cyton or nuikta but that seems like an awful hassel for your usecase.

Comment: Unfortunately not - at least not for the foreseeable future. I work at a large organization, this particular linux sever is primarily for a SAS environment. Maybe once the python user community within my company grows, this could be an option or a standalone server instance for Python processing.

Would there be other options I could explore for big data processing outside of connecting to the linux server in my original question?

Comment: Well you could run it on another server, i.e. in the cloud where your organization can pay for precisely the computing power you need and you wouldn't be bound to the corporate policies for on premise servers. If you're allowed to execute binaries in your usershare you could run your own python binary in your userspace which is a build of the latest python. However if you're not allowed to execute code on the server I have a hard time seeing how you'd utilize it's resources.